# Practice of storing default values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have column`code` in one of my tables, there should be a list of codes, which can be saved in database. Problem is that there is more then 100 of them, so I don't want to store them as a part of code or submit them through radio form.

What is more preferable way of solving this problem? Do projects store such values in separate database table? Or may be other common practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list of things is likely to change frequently, or you need to give access to change them somehow ... then yes, add them to a table in your DB and just create a `belongs_to` relationship from the model that needs to reference them.

If the list will never change, then why not make it an `enum` attribute, and just add the list to your model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum code: %i(code1 code2 code3 ... code99 code100)
end
```

You should define the `code` column as an `integer` within your migration file in order to correctly use this as an enum attribute.

Read more here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: thanks. The reason that I think I should store it in db is that I need some complicated validations for this entry, connected with other entries. Another option I'm thinking of is loading YML file from lib.

Comment: You can do just the same validations regardless of how you store the data.